# How to create a view of hierarchical taxonomies and each taxonomy lists all its nodes

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

How to create a view of hierarchical taxonomies and each taxonomy lists all its nodes?

```
Item1
--node1
--node2
Item1.1
--node3
Item1.2
--node4
Item2
Item2.1
--node5
```

Comment: not the same problem :(

Comment: what makes it different?

Comment: If it's not, please make it look different. Currently both questions shows exactly the same desired output.